# android get GPS location

Tags: android, gps, android-edittext

Im trying to get my GPS location into an editbox on the press of a button

When I click the button the GPS Icon comes on and starts flashing but its not till its stable that it will fill the editbox with the location so I have to press the button wait till the GPS icon is steady and then press the button again and it puts the location in the edit box

is there a way of doing it on one button press so that it waits until it has the GPS signal and only then fill the editbox with the location

My code is as follows

```
public void pickbtn(View view) {

         LocationManager mlocManager=null;
         LocationListener mlocListener;
         mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         mlocListener = new locapp();
         mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

         if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if(locapp.latitude>0)
            {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                int dd = c.get(Calendar.SHORT);
                Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                t.setToNow();
                String date = t.format("%d/%m/%y");

                String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatText);
                editText1.setText(mydate + ","+locapp.latitude + "," +locapp.longitude, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
             }
             else
             {
              }
          } else {
          }
      }
```

the locapp.java code is as follows

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class locapp implements LocationListener {
public static double latitude;
public static double longitude;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    latitude=loc.getLatitude();
    longitude=loc.getLongitude();
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
   //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
    //print "GPS got Enabled";
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
{
}
}
```

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Will Jamieson's answer. I am adding a class to get location from GPS. Add this GPSTracker class in your project: http://pastie.org/9300205

Take this globally:

```
GPSTracker gps;
```

Use this code in activity in onCreate:

```
gps = new GPSTracker(this);
```

Define this async in your class:

```
private class getGPSstuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Location l=gps.getLocation();
    latitude=l.getLatitude();
    longitude=l.getLongitude();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Set the text here
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 // you can make sure gps is available here and handle it if its not available here
 // optional tho
}
}
```

Use this on button click:

```
new getGpsStuff().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can put your GPS code in an `async` block and update the `EditText` in the `onPostExecute()` method. More on `AsyncTask` [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) .

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
private class getGPSstuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Run your GPS code here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Set the text here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
     // you can make sure gps is available here and handle it if its not available here
     // optional tho
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Im a bit of a noob on this so where do i put the getGPSstuff class in the locapp.java code or in the main code for the activity

Comment: I would recommend checking out this tut: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/  and then calling getLatitude() and getLongitude() in the doInBackground